# how to mvvm data-bind kendo radiobutton value attribute?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui, radio-button

I'm trying to bind my two radio buttons with kendo MVVM. However it always default to none of radio buttons checked. Is this a bug in kendo MVVM? I'm expecting one of the radio buttons to be checked the first time you see the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>

    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body id="main">
    <input type="radio" data-bind="value: Permission.Read, checked: checkedValue" name="RadioGroup0" />
    <input type="radio" data-bind="value: Permission.Modify, checked: checkedValue" name="RadioGroup0" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        viewModel = new kendo.observable({
            checkedValue: 2,
            Permission: {
                Read: 1,
                Modify: 2
            }
        });
        kendo.bind($("#main"), viewModel);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/bageveta/27/edit?html,console,output

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/elements

Comment: the demo has the value attribute hardcoded. which is not what i want.

Comment: if you get the value you want in a Jquery variable you could probably set that as the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the attr binding.

```html
<input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { value: Permission.Read }, checked: checkedValue" name="RadioGroup0"/>
<input type="radio" data-bind="attr: { value: Permission.Modify }, checked: checkedValue" name="RadioGroup0"/>
```

http://jsbin.com/bageveta/30/edit

Comment: Note that the order of the bindings matters. This does not work when the `checked` binding is before the `attr.value` binding.